# Form based JAAS - using same login form to log users in explicitly

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, authentication, jaas

Using form-based JAAS, MySQL, Apache TomEE, JSP, Servlets

I know how to configure form based JAAS to automatically redirects users to login page, when they try to access secured page. Basically, I have configured JDBC Realm for TomEE and MySQL (in `server.xml` file), in `web.xml` I have declared `<security-constraint>s`, `<security-role>s` and `<login-config>`.

Then, there is following login form:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="j_security_check" method="post">
        <h3>Login:</h3>
        <p>
            <label for="name">Username</label> <input name="j_username"
                id="username" type="text" required/>
            <!-- required -->
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password</label> <input name="j_password"
                id="password" type="text" required/>
            <!-- required -->
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

And, this works fine for pages that are declared inside `<security-constraint>` tags, in web.xml.

But, I would like to have explicit access to a page where user can log in. So, how should I approach to implementing this login system? I would like to use this login page I am using with declarative form-based JAAS.

I was thinking about to declare some jsp or servlet in web.xml as secured. Then, somewhere on the site, there will be a link that has URL of that secured jsp/servlet. So, when user clicks on the link he will be automatically redirected to `login` page (usual behavior in declarative form based JAAS). Then, after successful login, user will be redirected to the secured jsp/servlet.

Now, how can I make this secured jsp/servlet redirects to, lets say `/home` servlet? Problem is in this situation is not called HTTP get/post request, so implementing servlet doGet/doPost methods doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand clearly how form based security works, at the time of writing this question. I was thinking to use this login form "explicitly": just to go to this page, enter login details and press Submit button. But, as I understood, that can't be done when using form based security.

So, I have implemented this like: when user wants to login, user clicks on login link somewhere on the page, which is a link to secured, user account details jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, how can I make this secured jsp/servlet redirects to, lets say
>   /home servlet? Problem is in this situation is not called HTTP
>   get/post request, so implementing servlet doGet/doPost methods doesn't
>   help.

Instead of a redirect to /home, do a redirect to /homeredir.  Then /homeredir does a 302-redirect to /home.  (Or instead of a 302, does it via a JavaScript location.replace().)